# Datadog - Grok extraction not working as expected

Tags: logstash-grok, datadog

I crated a processor, using GROK, it reports no errors, and the sample displays the correct expected output.

But when I check the actual logs, it's as if nothing happened! the "User.Email" and "User.Id" properties do not show up!

Take a look:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure that your test case is representative of your logs and you don't have any sneaky whitespace characters or anything. Then I suggest removing the regex if possible and using the grok matchers. I know you can use the built-in `uuid` matcher for the Id; I can't recall if there is one for email.

Comment: the test case is an actual extraction from the logs, representing my own user (email was masked)... yet when I update my own token, I see the logs but the properties were not extracted!

Comment: My suggestion is still to remove the regex and use grok directly. Things get hard to debug and understand when there are multiple parsing engines involved. Use grokdebugger to help you construct it.